# How to use OData without the Entity Framework

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wcf-data-services, odata

I am interested in creating a OData wcf data service using visual studio 2012. However I do not want to use an entity model framework but rather use my scheme less nosql dataset to store and retrieve the data. 
Is there a way that allows me to take control of the odata services without being tide into a specific class structure such as Microsoft's entity framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Microsoft OData implementation without the Entity Framework. What you do need is an implementation of `IQueryable`. Here's an example OData service querying an array of objects:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.OData;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Builder;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Query;

// GET api/values
[ActionName("FromList")]
public IList<Poco> GetFromList(ODataQueryOptions<Poco> queryOptions)
{
    IQueryable<Poco> data = (
        new Poco[] { 
            new Poco() { id = 1, name = "one", type = "a" },
            new Poco() { id = 2, name = "two", type = "b" },
            new Poco() { id = 3, name = "three", type = "c" }
        })
        .AsQueryable();

    var t = new ODataValidationSettings() { MaxTop = 25 };
    queryOptions.Validate(t);

    var s = new ODataQuerySettings() { PageSize = 25 };
    IEnumerable<Poco> results =
        (IEnumerable<Poco>)queryOptions.ApplyTo(data, s);

    return results.ToList();
}

public class Poco
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This way though, wouldn't you lose the ability to filter at the db and instead would be performed in memory. Anyway elegant round that, without reimplementing the IQueryable interface?

Comment: @gdp Are you looking for something like [Simple.OData](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/686240/reasons-to-consume-OData-feeds-using-Simple-ODa)?

Comment: i will have a look, but ideally i want to parse the OData query and convert it to some sort of model where i can build the SQL dynamically. The data layer in the project im working on doesn't have the ability to return IQueryable and i still want the paging/filtering done at the db.